# Permission Denied For the My file in ec2 of aws , after executing all Methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

First see this

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-164 for-buildserver]$ ./launch-buildserver
-bash: ./launch-buildserver: Permission denied
```

`launch-buildserver` is my file that i am running through Linux AMI of aws but error come out , tried my best , search a lot but nothing happen please help

Comment: The file may need to be reachable/executable. To do so, you can check the file permissions by `ls -l launch-buildserver`. And if it looks stricter than it should be, run `chmod +x launch-buildserver` or such.

Comment: see this now                                                                                                         [ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-164 for-buildserver]$ chmod +x launch-buildserver
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-164 for-buildserver]$ ./launch-buildserver
: No such file or directory

Comment: anyone please help